# Resetting the check-box values in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement the reset function for the checkbox. Here is my test code but it is not giving the output.

```
      <html>
 <head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="dropdown" id="drop">
<form name="frmChkForm" id="frmChkForm">Checkme
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" class="group1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" class="group1">
</form>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="reset()"> Reset All </a>

<script>
 function reset() {
    $('dropdown input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); 
    console.log(1);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me regarding what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will probably do the trick:

```
$('#frmChkForm').find(':checked').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! this works fine! :)
Also if I have something like price range (using jQuery) inside the same form, how can I reset it with the same function ?

Comment: You could use something like `$( ".price" ).slider({ values: [ 0, 100 ] });` to set them back to the original positions

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Fix your html. You are missing a closing `>` in your dropdown div

Then you just need to modify your jquery selector:

```
$('.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]') // the . is for class, # is for id.
```